# Gathering AWS Lambda Execution Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless

I'm currently working on a dissertation project that involves comparing performance times between different serverless providers. In order to do this, I need to collect data on execution times.

Is there a way to easily gather execution times for Lambda functions and export them in bulk (to a spreadsheet, for example)? I've looked at CloudWatch Metrics, Logs and X-Ray traces and I can't find any option to export the performance data. The alternative is sifting through each execution in X-Ray or Logs and writing the execution time down manually into a spreadsheet, which would be crazy for hundreds of executions. Azure, for example, lets you export the execution data to a spreadsheet.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, the timestamps provided by the service (any service) are almost meaningless unless you are also capturing and accounting for start-to-finish time that isn't reflected there. Where is container preparation time tracked?  What kind of reuse occurs?  What's your round trip time to the service endpoint? How much time is spent in TLS negotiation, parsing, authentication, and other internal service operation that occurs before the actual invocation starts, and how much time does the service need in order to serialize and transmit the response back to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [export your CloudWatch logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/S3ExportTasksConsole.html) to S3. In short:

1. Create an S3 bucket
2. Allow the CloudWatch logs principal (e.g. `logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`) to access it.
3. Create a CloudWatch Logs export task from the Log Group to the S3 bucket.

Exporting CloudWatch *metrics* to S3 ist currently not supported. You could create your own tool that dumps this data to S3, e.g. by using [get-metric-statistics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudwatch/get-metric-statistics.html) or use an existing tool, like [this one](https://github.com/mogproject/cloudwatch-dump).

Comment: Ahhh, you've given me an idea. Export to S3 bucket, download JSON data from bucket, convert data from JSON to CSV, remove the fluff and I'm left with a spreadsheet of the execution times. Thanks!